# FFmpeg Infinite loop when probing stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

So, seems like ffmpeg is stuck in some kind of infinite loop when trying to probing stream 1. This happens only for one specific provider. I never see input/output in logs like for other streams.

I have tried to read it first with https://streamlink.github.io/ library - which works fine but ffmpeg doesn't stream this data anyway.
The stream I'm struggling with is using HLS.

I also tried to play around with probesize, max_probe_packets or analyzeduration but nothing happened.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit
cmd:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -re -probesize 10000 -max_probe_packets 10M -analyzeduration 100000 -i - -map a:0 -async 1 -acodec aac -f flv -fflags +discardcorrupt -fflags +fastseek -fflags +nobuffer -fflags +noparse rtmp://localhost:1935/live/edgestream3
```

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-re' ... matched as option 're' (read input at native frame rate) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-probesize' ... matched as AVOption 'probesize' with argument '10000'.
Reading option '-max_probe_packets' ... matched as AVOption 'max_probe_packets' with argument '10M'.
Reading option '-analyzeduration' ... matched as AVOption 'analyzeduration' with argument '100000'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '-'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument 'a:0'.
Reading option '-async' ... matched as option 'async' (audio sync method) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'aac'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option '-fflags' ... matched as AVOption 'fflags' with argument '+discardcorrupt'.
Reading option '-fflags' ... matched as AVOption 'fflags' with argument '+fastseek'.
Reading option '-fflags' ... matched as AVOption 'fflags' with argument '+nobuffer'.
Reading option '-fflags' ... matched as AVOption 'fflags' with argument '+noparse'.
Reading option 'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/edgestream4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option async (audio sync method) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url -.
Applying option re (read input at native frame rate) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: -.
[NULL @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Opening 'pipe:' for reading
[pipe @ 0x7fbb7d908140] Setting default whitelist 'crypto,data'
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=50
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] stream=0 stream_type=f pid=66 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] stream=1 stream_type=15 pid=1000 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:65536 seeks:0 nb_streams:2
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] parser not found for codec none, packets or times may be invalid.
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 0 pp:10000000
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Probe with size=189, packets=1 detected aac with score=1
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 0 pp:9999999
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Probe with size=381, packets=2 detected aac with score=1
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 0 pp:9999998
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Probe with size=576, packets=3 detected aac with score=51
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probed stream 0
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:10000000
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:9999999
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:9999998
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:9999997
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 11 got 10
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 15 got 14
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:9999996
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:9999995
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:9999994
[mpegts @ 0x7fbb7e80b400] probing stream 1 pp:9999993

so on so on...
```

edit2:
Tried cmd:

```
ffprobe stream_url -loglevel debug
```

with the response after a long time. How can I force ffmpeg to drop probing?

```
[mpegts @ 0x7f9155853400] probed stream 1 failed
[mpegts @ 0x7f9155853400] parser not found for codec none, packets or times may be invalid.
[hls @ 0x7f9155813200] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5013600 microseconds st:2
[hls @ 0x7f9155813200] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Unknown: none ([21][0][0][0] / 0x0015)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[hls @ 0x7f9155813200] Could not find codec parameters for stream 3 (Unknown: none ([21][0][0][0] / 0x0015)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
```

Comment: 1) You didn't show your command, so we don't know what you tried. 2) Show the output **without** `-hide_banner` because it hides important info.

Comment: Sorry, assumed that command from log (reading option) will work. 
'ffmpeg -loglevel debug -re -probesize 10000 -max_probe_packets 10M -analyzeduration 100000 -i - -map a:0 -async 1 -acodec aac -f flv -fflags +discardcorrupt -fflags +fastseek -fflags +nobuffer -fflags +noparse rtmp://localhost:1935/live/edgestream3'


I will add new log in few hours when problematic stream will be available.

Comment: @llogan output updated.